# Plums half sweet and half sour

Tags: fruit-trees, fruits, plums

When I purchased my house last year I hoped that the tree with purple leaves in my front yard would produce fruit. Fortunately it has produced little plums about the size of a golf ball. This is my first experience owning a fruit tree so I apologize if the following is a silly question.

When I pick a plum that appears to be ripe, half of the flesh is sweet and the other half **of the same plum** is sour. I don't recall experiencing this with plums or other stone fruit I've purchased from the supermarket. In the supermarket stone fruit generally has a uniform flavor throughout. Is this a normal occurrence for little plums like these? If so is there anything I can do now to encourage the entire plum to be sweet now? If that ship has sailed what can I do so the plums are more uniformly sweeter next year?

Comment: Other than "wait for it to be all ripe, rather than half-ripe", none I can think of.

Comment: Okay, I guess it is a silly question then and the answer is to just be patient.

Comment: How far apart are the plums on the branches? And how dense are the branches? I do think you need to be more patience, but if the tree has not been pruned and the fruit has not been thinned either of those issues could be affecting your fruit.

Comment: @michelle The plums are pretty densely packed, but I don't know if they are abnormally so. I pruned back the tree somewhat last year shortly after buying the house. My goal was mostly to thin out obvious sucker branches, keep it away from the house, and make it so it doesn't bother people walking on the sidewalk. At the time I didn't have much faith it would fruit so I didn't look up proper pruning technique.

Comment: In the future, try thinning out the fruit so there is no more than one fruit per spur and no fruit is closer than 2-4 inches from another. That should help. If the fruit is growing too densely, it won't ripen well.